# EclipseLink Moxy query by xpath using getValueByXPath

Tags: xml, xpath, eclipselink, moxy

Given xml as follows:

```
 <test>
 <AlternateID>
      <System>xyz</System>
      <Type>four</Type>
      <Value>0</Value>
   </AlternateID>
   <AlternateID>
      <System>abc</System>
      <Type>one</Type>
      <Value>145287</Value>
      <Version>01</Version>
   </AlternateID>
   <AlternateID>
      <System>def</System>
      <Type>two</Type>
      <Value>123456</Value>
      <Version>1</Version>
   </AlternateID>
   <AlternateID>
      <System>ghi</System>
      <Type>three</Type>
      <Value>17032</Value>
   </AlternateID>
   </test>
```

Using eclipselink moxy for parsing the data and using getValueByXPath to get the values by querying using xpath. It works wonderfully except in the case if I use the following xpath

```
test/AlternateID[System='abc' and Type='one']/Value/text()
```

Appreciate if anyone can share any success with this, basically using 'AND' in xpath for selecting nodes based on values.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't use that but can you try:
`test/AlternateID[System/text()='abc' and Type/text()='one']/Value/text()`

Comment: i have tried it as well but not working. i wonder if this feature is available in moxy getValueByXPath itself, as in the test cases I do not see such xpath being tested.

https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/moxy/eclipselink.moxy.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/jaxb/jaxbcontext/GetByXPathTests.java